# FileSystemWatcher takes memory after disposing?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a program using FileSystemWatcher class. It works by adding new FileSystemWatcher on each subfolder in a folder, each FileSystemWatcher takes 8 kB of memory.

The FileSystemWatchers are added to the list "watchers" where can be thousands of them.

When I call method

```
 watchers.ForEach(x => x.Dispose());
```

I expected all of them to stop (which they did), but **no memory is freed from RAM**.

How can I fix this please?

```
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {                        
                    watchers.ForEach(x => x.Dispose());
                    watchers.Clear();
                }
                disposed = true;
            }                
        }
```

Comment: Won't [`IncludeSubdirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx) help to watch over sub folders instead of creating many watchers?

Comment: `Dispose` releases unmanaged resources, but does not free managed memory.

Comment: IncludeSubdirectories was my first try, but when there is a lot of "movement", buffer was not big enough and I read somewhere that's better to create more smaller watchers.

Comment: Did you subscribe to any of the [`FileWatcher` events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_events(v=vs.110).aspx)? If so, then the object which subscribed to the event will have a reference to the `FileWatcher` object until such time as the subscriber unsubscribes from the event, or the subscriber is itself garbage collected - so the subscriber will keep alive the `FileWatcher` even if you think you've disposed it and removed all other references to it.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov How can I free managed memory?

Comment: Should unsubscribe these events first? I thought that Dispose() is doing it.

Comment: No, `Dispose()` does NOT unsubscribe - you must do it manually. This is true for all types, not just `FileSystemWatcher`. Just remember that whenever you subscribe using `source.SomeEvent += someHandler()`, the right-hand-side keeps the left-hand-side in memory until either the subscriber is garbage collected, or you call `source.SomeEvent -= someHandler()`

Answer (score 0):

When you've placed all the watchers into list - you have created references from list to them, so garbage collector can't free memory taken by watchers while this list is "alive".

You have to remove them from the list also:

```
watchers.Clear();
```

Also if you have other references to your watchers (including event handlers subscribed to their events) - you have to clear these references (unsubscribe from events too) in order for garbage collector to free memory taken by watchers.

In any case you should not expect memory to be freed instantly. Garbage collector is not running all the time so it can take a time for memory to be free.

You can force garbage collector to free memory with [GC.Collect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collect(v=vs.110).aspx), but usually it is not recommended.

Comment: It's not working. What I'm I doing wrong? I will update main post.

Comment: I can see why  GC.Collect() is not reccomended - the program crashes. ;-)

Comment: @JosefKvita Typicaly it should not crash. Anyway, calling `Collect` is bad practice, garbage collector usually does its job well automatically.